# Problem with the animation of chart displaying dynamic data

Tags: javascript, echarts

I am facing a problem with the animation of lines charts using echarts.js (https://echarts.baidu.com/dist/echarts.min.js)
I am able to load the data into series after an interval of 5 seconds. but it refresh the whole chart, due to which the feel of animation is ruined.
Is there any way that can help me load/remove a part of my data from the series without effecting the animation of whole chart?

I have tried multiple ways including:

```
     mychart.getOption();
     mychart.setSeries();
```

But both of these refresh the whole chart. but i want to add the new data only without any blinking effect on whole chart.

```
    setInterval(function () {
        hitslines.lines=[];
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://whos.amung.us/stats/data/?jte1b90n&k=dzsg93pq&pins=new",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                for (var i = 0; i < response.pins.length; i++) {
                    hitslines.lines.push([
                        [
                            parseFloat(response.pins[i].lon),
                            parseFloat(response.pins[i].lat),
                        ],

                        [
                            parseFloat(officesLocations.offices[0].value[0]),
                            parseFloat(officesLocations.offices[0].value[1]),
                        ]
                    ]);


                }
            },
            async: false
        });
        if (count == 0){
            count += 1
            myChart.setOption({
                series: [{
                    name:'line',
                    data:  hitslines.lines
                }]
            });
        }
        myChart.setOption({
            series: [
            {
                name:'series2',
                data:  hitslines.lines
            }]
        });   
    }, 5000);
```

I want to display all of new visitors based on latitude and longitude from response after every 5 second and remove the lines from chart of those visitors who are not currently active. Simply, if the new response doesn't have the latitude longitude of visitors from the previous response, remove those lines from the chart. 
My chart blinks after every 5 second. I just don't want that.

Comment: Are you having any success with this issue?  I'm coding a digital sign with gauges for production efficiency and units produced and the gauges animates back to zero then to the new value.  I'm also have a memory leak issue over time.  I'm using setTimeout (not setInterval) and wonder if animation could be the culprit.

Comment: I don't know your exact issue, but i think you should only keep the data that is being displayed.